# Query a List of Objects

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a class called Activity with properties as below:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public DateTime ActivityDate { get; set; }
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
private string _description;
public string Description
{
  get { return Description; }
  set { _description = value; }
}
// Enum that we will use for filtering later on 
public ActivityType TypeOfActivity { get; set; }
```

I display the objects on a listbox which you can add over and back and one requirement is that you add a running cost of the list. I have three lists

```
List<Activity> activityList = new List<Activity>();
List<Activity> selectedList = new List<Activity>();
List<Activity> filteredList = new List<Activity>();
```

Screen shot:

[image: Screenshot of the application screen]

I was wondering what way would I be fit to access the Cost property in the list selectedList so I could maybe calculate them in a foreach loop.

Or maybe there would be a more appropriate way of doing so. I have had a fair read through a few articles but with no avail.

Comment: You didn't show us a ViewModel or other implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: And it is not clear what "calculate them" means. Sum the value sin selectedList?

Comment: I meant to add all the Costs of the activity objects that I added

Comment: What is your ViewModel (or DataContext) ?

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ [`Sum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum?view=netframework-4.8)

`decimal totalCost = selectedList.Sum(activity => activity.Cost);`